# Python: How to plot a conditional cumulative frequency histogram?

Tags: python

I have this list of data for which I would like to plot a histogram chart. However the graph is not very readable for large values ​​of the X axis and are not really important to keep them.

Here is a sub sample of my data:

```
print(v)

1      1738   #the values ​​I want to plot on the histogram
2      2200
3      1338
4      1222
5       939
6       898
```

I calculated the cumulative frequency as follows:

```
v = x.cumsum()
t = [round(100*v/x.sum(),2)]
t
```

and the output is:

```
 1        9.90
 2       22.44
 3       30.06
 4       37.02
 5       42.37
```

How can I represent on the histogram only the data for which the cumulative frequency is less than or equal to 40%?

I don't know how to do in python, thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **short answer** is: Slice the numpy array to filter values <= 40%. For example, if `a` is a 1D numpy array:

```
a[a <= 40]
```

A longer answer is provided by the example below, which shows:

- A generation of normally distributed random data (as the provided dataset is very small)
- Performing your calculation on the numpy array
- Slicing the array to return values which are <= 40%
- Plotting the results using the [Plotly library](https://plotly.com/python/histograms/) - API only.

#### Example code:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.io as pio

# Generate random dataset (for demo only).
np.random.seed(1)
X = np.random.normal(0, 1, 10000)

# Calculate the cumulative frequency.
X_ = np.cumsum(X)*100/X.sum()
data = X_[X_ <= 40]

# Plot the histogram.
pio.show({'data': {'x': data, 
                   'type': 'histogram', 
                   'marker': {'line': {'width': 0.5}}},
          'layout': {'title': 'Cumulative Frequency Demo'}})
```

#### Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank You for ure answer @S3DEV , but i have this error :

Comment: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Ok, no worries. This is a general error which can apply to many things.  I've just copied/pasted the code above and run with no errors. Please let me know which line is triggering the error. The traceback will tell you.

Comment: your code works great! But it is by applying on my data that it shows me the error;
I think this is because my list is calculated as follows:
x = dff['Quantity'].value_counts().sort_index()


PS: dff is another database

Comment: Right, so you're working with a Series, and need to be working with a numpy array. Add this to the end: `.to_numpy()` which will return the data from the Series as a numpy array.  For example: `x = dff['Quantity'].value_counts().sort_index().to_numpy()`